# Is there any COVID restriction to do a layover in Paris, France?

Tags: airports, france, layovers, paris

A friend from Brasil is coming to Spain and she's found a flight from Sao Paulo with a layover in Paris Charles de Gaulle. She has the Italian passport too. Will she have to do any test or provide any additional documents whatsoever?

Answer (score 4):

> Will she have to do any test or provide any additional documents whatsoever?

Yes. https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php -> France

> 4. A **completed International Travel Certificate** must be presented prior to boarding and to immigration upon arrival or **when transiting France**. The certificate can be obtained at consulates or at https://www.interieur.gouv.fr.
>
> - This does not apply to passengers arriving from Andorra, Australia, Canada, Georgia, Japan, Korea (Rep.), Monaco, New Zealand, Rwanda, San Marino, Switzerland, Thailand, Tunisia, United Kingdom, Uruguay, Vatican City (Holy See) or an EEA Member State.

Same info on http://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html